# how I can take the input from for loop and add it to the second input from loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to take first value the user will enter and add it to the second value he will enter.

```py
z=int(input("enter number of values needs for equal : "))

for i in range(z):
    print(" numbers ",i)
    value=input()

print(equal)
```

Comment: please add some test case to understand better and what is equal in last statement ??

Comment: Use a list, and append to the list.

Comment: like if the user add in loop 3 program will ask him 3 time to enter a value after the program will take all the values and make a sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please evaluate your query in your future posts.I think this may help you.

```
equal = 0
z=int(input("enter number of values needs for equal : "))

for i in range(z):
    print(" numbers ",i)
    value=int(input())
    equal = equal + value
print(equal)
```

Comment: thank you very much,I click double time on evaluate ^^ it's canceled sorry I'm new in this website, thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```py
z=int(input("enter number of values needs for equal : "))

value_list=[]

for i in range(z):
    print(" numbers ",i)
    value=input()
    value_list.append(value)



print(equal)
```

You could create a list an for every number in the `z`-input the user have to write a new number and then the number get added to the `value_list`

Comment: I want the number added by the user in value=input()  make sum for it